# Create circular progress bar cropped on the bottom

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, frontend

I'm trying to figure out how to create a circular progress bar
that is cropped on the bottom like this one: [PROGRESS BAR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNA8G.png) but I can't find such component.
Do you guys have any idea ?
Preferable with Material UI

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like `react-progressbar-semicircle`

https://github.com/ThomasBem/react-progressbar-semicircle